# Delete a user from TFS project using Powershell or C#

Tags: tfs

Need a powershell or c# script to delete a user from TFS project.i have tried to search in google but only code to list the user permission in each project no code to delete a user from team project using script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`tfssecurity /g-`](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/command-line/tfssecurity-cmd#g--remove-a-user-or-group) command in your script to remove a user or a user group from an existing group.

```
tfssecurity /g- groupIdentity memberIdentity [/collection:CollectionURL] [/server:ServerURL]
```

> **Remarks**
>
> Run this command on an application-tier server for Team Foundation.
>
> **Examples**
>
> The following example removes the Datum1 domain user John Peoples
>   (Datum1\jpeoples) from the Team Foundation Administrators group.
>
> ```
> tfssecurity /g- "Team Foundation Administrators" n:Datum1\jpeoples /server:http://ADatumCorporation:8080
> ```